# Reputation graph on user profile showing wrong data

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

I was checking [my reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2723943/khan-imran-ali?tab=reputation&sort=graph) and found that it is showing wrong data.

Clicking on a bar shows the previous day's reputation changes, and not that day's reputation changes.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I don't see reputation changes of that magnitude on those days (either June, July or February).

Comment: @Makoto I've edited the question. I hope that is what the OP meant.

Comment: @CoolGuy: It seems to me that you've grossly reworded the question.  Further, the sudden spike/loss can be explained quite easily; they won a 500 rep bounty, then started a 500 rep bounty shortly thereafter.

Comment: @CollGuy Thanks for edit, you are right,

Comment: I have the same little bug. It may be related to the time zone of the user : I am in France. As I click on a day, I get details on what happened the day before (if something happened...).  Consequently, I cannot get details on days followed by no-reputation days since I cannot click on these no-reputation days. An obvious solution is to gain (or loose)  reputation every day...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (using Firefox from Greece). I recall that this was working properly some moths ago. Moreover, when I mouse-over the current day's reputation bar, it shows me yesterday's date